# Retornar contagem de linhas de uma consulta

Tags: php, query, mysql-num-rows

Estou tentando validar um login utilizando contagem de linhas de uma consulta, mas não estou conseguindo:

Minha conexão está assim:

```
include("defines.php");
try {
  $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=' . HOST . ';dbname=' . DB, USER, PASS );
  $PDO->exec("set names utf8");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Erro de conexão ao Banco de Dados: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Meu formulário está assim:

```
<form class="userform" id="frmLogin" method="post" action="verifica_usuario.php">
    <input type="text" size="35" id="usuario" name="usuario"  value="<?php echo $_POST['usuario']; ?>" />

    <input type="password" size="35" class="bradius" id="senha" name="senha" value="<?php echo $_POST['senha']; ?>" />

    <spam  class="button" ><a href="#" class="button"  onClick="frmLogin.submit();" onMouseOver="window.status='';return true" /> Entrar</a>
    </spam>
   </form>
```

A Página que faz a validação está assim:

```
session_start();  // Inicia a session
include "libraries/conn.php";

@$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
@$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$senhacrip = md5($senha);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='{$usuario}' AND senha='{$senhacrip}' AND ativado='S'");
    $login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

Porém, ao executar o código, o navegador retorna a mensagem:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in D:\xampp\htdocs\n_archaeus\verifica_usuario.php on line 22

Comment: printa o var_dump($sql); pra saber o que tá chegando. e tb  var_dump("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='{$usuario}' AND senha='{$senhacrip}' AND ativado='S'"); pra ver a select q tá montando

Comment: Você está abrindo a conexão usando PDO e usando `mysql` para trabalhar no banco. Estude um pouco sobre a biblioteca PDO para não precisar usar outra biblioteca de acesso ao banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Se sua conexão usa PDO continue a trabalhar com PDO**

```
$sql = $PDO->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='{$usuario}' AND senha='{$senhacrip}' AND ativado='S'");
$login_check = $sql->fetchColumn();
echo $login_check; //retorna 1 caso haja usuario e 0 se não houver
```